# How to generate a plot for reported values and missing values in R - timeseries

Tags: r, plot

Hi I am using R to analyze my data. I have time-series data in following format:

```
dates        ID
2008-02-12   3
2008-03-12   3
2008-05-12   3
2008-09-12   3
2008-02-12   8
2008-04-12   6
```

I would like to create a plot with dates at the x axis and `ID` on Y axis. Such that it draws a point if  id is reported for that data and nothing if there is no data for that.

In the original dataset I only have id if the value is reported on that date. For e.g. for 2008-02-12 for id 6 there is no data reported hence it is missing in my dataset.

I was able to get all the dates with unique(`df$dates`) function, but dont know enough about R data structures on how to  loop through data and make matrix with 1 0 for all ids and then plot it.

I will be grateful if you guys can help me with the code or give me some pointers on what could be effective way to approach this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So basically, do you want a scatter-plot of your data ? If not, please post a picture of your desired chart using your example data as input...

Comment: It's not only guys here, there are girls at SO too ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want something like a scatter-plot :

```
# input data
DF <- 
read.csv(
text=
'Year,ID 
2008-02-12,3 
2008-03-12,3 
2008-05-12,3 
2008-09-12,3 
2008-02-12,8 
2008-04-12,6',
colClasses=c('character','integer'))

# convert first column from characters to dates
DF$Year <- as.POSIXct(DF$Year,format='%Y-%m-%d',tz='GMT')

# scatter plot
plot(x=DF$Year,y=DF$ID,type='p',xlab='Date',ylab='ID', 
     main='Reported Values',pch=19,col='red')
```

**Result :**

[image]

But this approach has a problem. For example if you have `unique(ids) = c(1,2,1000)` the space on the y axis between `id=2` and `id=1000` will be very big (the same holds for the dates on the x axis).

Maybe you want a sort of "map" id-dates, like the following :

```
# input data
DF <- 
read.csv(
text=
'Year,ID 
2008-02-12,3 
2008-03-12,3 
2008-05-12,3 
2008-09-12,3 
2008-02-12,8 
2008-04-12,6',
colClasses=c('character','integer'))

dates <- as.factor(DF$Year)
ids <- as.factor(DF$ID)

plot(x=as.integer(dates),y=as.integer(ids),type="p",
     xlim=c(0.5,length(levels(dates))+0.5),
     ylim=c(0.5,length(levels(ids))+0.5),
     xaxs="i", yaxs="i",
     xaxt="n",yaxt="n",main="Reported Values",
     xlab="Date",ylab="ID",pch=19,col='red')

axis(1,at=1:length(levels(dates)),labels=levels(dates))
axis(2,at=1:length(levels(ids)),labels=levels(ids))

# add grid
abline(v=(1:(length(levels(dates))-1))+0.5,,col="Gray80",lty=2)
abline(h=(1:(length(levels(ids))-1))+0.5,col="Gray80",lty=2)
```

**Result :**

[image]

Comment: Perhaps since its time-series they might want lines?  Just a thought.

Comment: @RichardScriven: since he wrote about unique(dates) I think he wants to visualize a sort of map ID - DATE with a point indicating where a correspondence exists. Have a look at my edit ;)

Comment: @digEmAll Thank you so much for such an elaborate answer. I do have 5 year, approx (one week apart) data with about 5000 ids and my idea was to visualize when top 200 or 300 ids were active in those years. As @ Richard suggested, i will try to plot lines, but my hunch was that lines will take more space and it would be really hard to visualize then. One last question though, is it possible to condense x-axis, so the points plotted are relatively close and might look like a line if the ids are active for consecutive period of time. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user984201: the x-axis with 5 year of data will definitely be condensed, you won't need any "trick". Anyway, it's still not completely clear to me what are you trying to accomplish... IMHO lines seem not really appropriate for this case... could you please draw a picture of your desired result and add it to your original post ?